# How can I format a numpy array to be displayed without excessive 0s without losing its alignment?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, formatting

I'm trying to display a numpy array that represents a matrix with big numbers in a compact manner without losing the alignment of columns and rows.

My code is as follows:

```py
EA = 1.8e8
EI = 1.8e7
L = 3

K = np.matrix([
    [EA/L, 0, 0, -EA/L, 0, 0],
    [0, 12*EI/(L**3), 6*EI/(L**2), 0, -12*EI/(L**3), 6*EI/(L**2)],
    [0, 6*EI/(L**2), 4*EI/L, 0, -6*EI/(L**2), 2*EI/L],
    [-EA/L, 0, 0, EA/L, 0, 0],
    [0, -12*EI/(L**3), -6*EI/(L**2), 0, 12*EI/(L**3), -6*EI/(L**2)],
    [0, 6*EI/(L**2), 2*EI/L, 0, -6*EI/(L**2), 4*EI/L]
])
print(K)
```

When executed without changing any option it displays like this:

```py
[[ 60000000.         0.         0. -60000000.         0.         0.]
 [        0.   8000000.  12000000.         0.  -8000000.  12000000.]
 [        0.  12000000.  24000000.         0. -12000000.  12000000.]
 [-60000000.         0.         0.  60000000.         0.         0.]
 [        0.  -8000000. -12000000.         0.   8000000. -12000000.]
 [        0.  12000000.  12000000.         0. -12000000.  24000000.]]
```

As you can see, it is nicely aligned but there is a lot of space being unnecessarily used by 0s.

I have tried using `np.set_printoptions` but it doesn't change anything unless I manually add a formatter for floats, which I have tried:

```py
mapper = lambda x: np.format_float_scientific(x,precision=3)
np.set_printoptions(
    precision=4, linewidth=150, 
    suppress=False, formatter={'float': mapper}
)
```

However, the output gets very untidy and harder to read:

```py
[[6.e+07 0.e+00 0.e+00 -6.e+07 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 8.e+06 1.2e+07 0.e+00 -8.e+06 1.2e+07]
 [0.e+00 1.2e+07 2.4e+07 0.e+00 -1.2e+07 1.2e+07]
 [-6.e+07 0.e+00 0.e+00 6.e+07 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 -8.e+06 -1.2e+07 0.e+00 8.e+06 -1.2e+07]
 [0.e+00 1.2e+07 1.2e+07 0.e+00 -1.2e+07 2.4e+07]]
```

How can I display the matrix aligned but using scientific notation to reduce space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you (you can modify it to your desire):

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':lambda x:format(x,' 6.1E') if x >= 0 else format(x,'6.1E')})
```

output:

```
[[ 6.0E+07  0.0E+00  0.0E+00 -6.0E+07  0.0E+00  0.0E+00]
 [ 0.0E+00  8.0E+06  1.2E+07  0.0E+00 -8.0E+06  1.2E+07]
 [ 0.0E+00  1.2E+07  2.4E+07  0.0E+00 -1.2E+07  1.2E+07]
 [-6.0E+07  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  6.0E+07  0.0E+00  0.0E+00]
 [ 0.0E+00 -8.0E+06 -1.2E+07  0.0E+00  8.0E+06 -1.2E+07]
 [ 0.0E+00  1.2E+07  1.2E+07  0.0E+00 -1.2E+07  2.4E+07]]
```